# Add rows to @html.Textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I add rows to this helper:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.xxx[i].xxx,  htmlAttributes:  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It seems like the default is 2 rows, I would like to add to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `rows` attribute

```
new { @class = "form-control", rows = "10" }
```

Change `10` with the number of rows you want